# How to reload the main component after redirecting to the another page Angular 7

Tags: angular, redirect

I have an Angular page after login dashboard is loading in that page. I have header in the app Component and there are some details loaded from the local storage of the browser. But after routed to the dashboard the header icons are not loading because I have set a ngIf condition to the header icons like follows

```js
<button
      *ngIf="isLoggedIn == 'true'"
      mat-icon-button
      (click)="snav.toggle()"
    >
      <mat-icon style="color:white;">menu</mat-icon>
    </button>
```

If the local storage LoggedIn value is true only this button is visible.

But in my case After hitting the login button in my login component it call a service and from there I have set local storage values.

```js
if (res1["retFlag"] === "0") {
            this.http
              .post("http://213.136.79.138:8080/gdp/login", obj, httpOptions)
              .subscribe(
                res => {
                  console.log(res);
                  // console.log('userid' + '' + res['userid']);

                  // tslint:disable-next-line:no-string-literal
                  if (res["returnFlag"] === 0) {
                    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-string-literal
                    const userid = res["loginEmployeeId"];
                    const username = res["username"];
                    localStorage.setItem("userid", userid);
                    localStorage.setItem("isLoggedIn", "true");
                    localStorage.setItem("username", username);
                    console.log(username);
                    // console.log('signed in log val:' + localStorage.getItem('isLoggedIn'));

                    //window.location.href = "./dashboard";

                    //this.router.navigate(["dashboard"]);

                    // var url = '@Url.Action("Action", "/dashboard")';
                    // window.location.href = url;

                    this.router.navigateByUrl("dashboard");

                    // this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
                  } else {
                    alert("Username or Password Incorrect");
                  }
                },
                err => {
                  // this.loading = false;
                  console.log(err);
                }
              );
          } else {
            alert("UserName Not Available");
          }
        },
        err => {
          // this.loading = false;
          console.log(err);
        }
      );
```

But the problem is header is not refreshed after redirect.

If I use **window.location.href = "dashboard"** working fine in local development server. But when hosted to the tomcat it is not working. Can some one suggest a solution for this problem

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, one of the solution will be subscribing to router events and do whatever you want. It will look like this

```
this.router.events.subscribe(val => {
    // do what you want
    // ...
});
```

and of course you will need to inject the router which will have the type of Router.

```
constructor(private router: Router) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Over and above @hayk's approach, you can even create a `BehaviorSubject` which can be subscribed to by the main component.

Apart from the solution to your problem, I would suggest you to implement the login process as a service which won't just have the login logic but also the token refresh logic (I am sure you would want to implement that as well)

The advantage of doing so is that you can call the service method not just after logging in but for various other scenarios as

1. Validating the login token whenever you are fetching data from the server
2. in between switching routes by subscribing to event changes in your app.component
3. Use `CanActivate` route guard in case you have some admin level components to first check for elevated access and then activate the route.